# Multi Line input using Perl/Tk

Tags: perl, user-interface, perltk

I was trying GUI in Perl using Perl/Tk. I couldn't find a way to take multi line text input from the user using any widget. For single line "Entry" can be used but I could find nothing for multi line input. Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mulit-line input is done with the `text` widget, as in:

```
# Text widget 20 characters wide and 10 lines tall
$mw->Text(-width => 20, -height => 10)->pack;
```

If you're new to Perk/Tk, I strongly suggest running `widget` from the command line.  It's an interactive demo (with code explanations) of Tk widgets and their options.